# Laravel: Text Wrap Laravel pulling infromation From DB

Tags: css, laravel

So i have pulled information from my database to display onto my page. Now i have that information displayed within a box however the information is actually out of the box and makes the page look very ugly:
[image]

Search.blade:

```
          .about {
            position: relative;
            left: 222px;
            top:153px;
           }

         .box {
           border: 1px solid;
           border-color: orange;
           padding: 10px;
           box-shadow: 5px 10px #ff9933;
           height: 300px;
           width: 1100px;
           position: relative;
           top: 20px;
          }

          <div class= "about">
              <p>{{ $post->About }}</p>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in: https://codepen.io/ron7/pen/YzXmgNa

you need to add: `word-wrap: break-word;` in `.box{}`, and change `left:222px;` to `margin-left: 222px;` in `.about{}`

Comment: wouldnt i have to specify the position of the word break though ?

Comment: no. You can read on CSS documentation, so you understand the how an why :)

Comment: cause i tried this and it didnt work also do you have the css documentation

Comment: i understand your point, but this is data being pulled from my database so my code isnt hard coded.

Comment: you can replace the data with `{{ $post->About }}`. What I've put is only  A LONG TEXT to SHOW the solution..... Check the CSS, and mainly in .about try to change `left` with `margin-left` As when you used left it pushed it out of the box...

Comment: Code only answers or "try this" answers can almost always be improved by editing them to include some explanation of how and why they work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
.about {
  position: relative;
  left: 222px;
  top:153px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```